# Standard approach to assign default value in Java

Tags: java

Often I invoke alien methods which might return a null value. In order to avoid simple null checks like

```
if (myVariable != null) {
     // do something
}
```

I sometimes assign a default value, like this:

```
myVariable = (myVariable == null) ? defaultValue : myVariable;
```

This seems a little bit redundant in Ruby for instance, there is the `||=` operator

I am not asking for such an operator, but my standard approach with the ternary operator seems a little bit redundant or maybe also confusing?

What better ways are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (myVariable == null) {
    myVariable = defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as the ternary variation?

Comment: @Nanne: No because it's simpler to read and avoids an unnecessary assignment when `myVariable != null` (the unnecessary assignment might be removed by the JIT compiler).

Comment: I way prefer this to the evil, ugly ternary operator. This is so easy to read and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If the alien method maybe return null value, it should note about null return value in method's Java docs. The client uses that alien method must check, but no way, the return value.

The simple way to do this:

```
retVal = alienMethod();
if (retVal == null) {
    retVal = defaultVal;
}
```

If you still want to avoid checking null value, the method that return the value must be in responsible for return default value. But what is your default value? Depend on your return type, you can create a dummy class to represent your default value instead of returning null value.

Answer (score 0):

There are no better/shorter/nicer ways to do it....

There was talk about introducing a '?' operator for null values in Java 7, but the concept got shifted out of the release.... maybe for Java 8 ?

https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_final_five

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/10/null-safe-type-java-7-nullpointerexception.html

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000047.html

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no "elegant" way.  If the variable is a field of your class, you can do it in the setter or getter.  But proper javadocs (which I don't show below!) are important to explain what happens to nulls.  e.g.

```
   public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
      this.foo = foo != null ? foo : DEFAULT_FOO;
   }

   public Foo getFoo() {
      return foo != null ? foo : DEFAULT_FOO;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the assigning of a default value into a small utility function and put it in a helper class. For variables of type `String`, this would look like this:

```
public static String unNull(String val,String defVal) {
    return (val==null ? defVal : val);
}
```

Then, in your code you can just write

```
myVariable = unNull(alienMethod(),defaultValue);
```

Using a static import, you can do without prefixing the static method's name with the class name.

You can also make a generic method to handle this (to template the type of both arguments and the return type), but I'm not sure it would work without an additional parameter of type `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

There is finally a better way to do it: [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) in Java 8. Instead of

```
Foo myVariable = bar();
myVariable = (myVariable == null) ? defaultValue : myVariable;
```

where `bar()` may return `null`, now you do

```
Foo myVariable = Optional.ofNullable(bar()).orElse(defaultValue).get()
```